# Find x and y position with angles in 3D world

Tags: c#, xna, camera, monogame, coordinates

I'm actually creating a Tracking Camera (or 3rd person camera), and to do so, I used two angles (X and Y) for the rotation of the camera and an other floating value for the distance between the target and the camera.

The camera system works fine, but I am searching a way to calculate the position of the correct position of the camera (for debug purpose only)

Do you have an idea of how I can do to figure it out?

This is the camera update function:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  this.View = 
    Matrix.CreateTranslation( 0, 0, 0 ) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationY( MathHelper.ToRadians( this.RotationAngle ) ) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationX( MathHelper.ToRadians( this.ArcAngle ) ) *
    Matrix.CreateLookAt(
      new Vector3( 0, 0, -this.Distance ), 
      this.TrackingPosition, 
      Vector3.Up );

  Viewport _viewport = this.graphicsDevice.Viewport;
  Single _aspectRatio = (Single)_viewport.Width / (Single)_viewport.Height;

  this.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
    MathHelper.PiOver4, 
    _aspectRatio, 
    NEAR_PLAN, FAR_PLAN );

  // Find x and y
  this.Position = new Vector3( 0, 0, -this.Distance );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

polar to cartesian in 3d ([spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system))

x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi)

y = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi)

z = r * cos(theta)

where theta and phi are your x , y angles

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I just implement those formulas and it works perfectly. Thank you!